# Pendrive recognized as USB 1.1 device

Tags: usb, usb-storage, usb-2, usb-hub

I have just pluged-in my old USB pendrive to simple nettop with Windows 7 on board. I used every of three USB ports and in each of them I saw standard Windows notice, that this device can work much faster, if I connect it to USB 2.0 port. And any attempt of copying files was awfully slow. I.e. Total Commander estimated, that it will need 3 hours 22 minutes to transfer 3,57 GB of `.mp3` files.

I understand this situation that, Windows detects my device as USB 2.0, but claims that all USB ports in my computer are USB 1.1. Am I right?

I have then connected my A4Tech keyboard (with USB hub) to each of these USB ports and then stick the very same USB pendrive to each of two keyboard's USB ports and... in every combination I have never seen that notice. My device was detected as USB 2.0 pendrive connected to USB 2.0 port. And -- of course -- transfer speeds were enormously higher. Total Commander estimated, that to copy the very same 3,57 GB of data it will only need around 12 minutes.

What am I missing? How can Windows detect the very same USB port (and the very same USB device) once as USB 1.1 and once as USB 2.0? How can plugging USB keyboard / USB hub in beetween change anything? The whole situation sounds for me like a little bit absurd.

Comment: Sounds like windows is slow to refresh the ports in between swapping devices. Ports in keyboards are usually 1.1.

Comment: No, and no. When connecting directly to computer, device was detected as  USB 1.1 from the very first time, so there is no delay on swapping devices, because there was no swap at the very first moment. And -- it seems, that KV300H has USB 2.0 hub on board.